# Undefined values for JQuery checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 checkboxes but they are showing as undefined in an alert box. Is there a trick to getting them to show a value? I tried putting a value of 1 in the input tag but it still reports as undefined.

Ok, thanks.. Here is some code.

```
        else if (item.field == "admCustRptDly" && item.value == "1")
        {
          $('#admCustRptDly').attr('checked', true);
        }

        else if (item.field == "admCustRptSumm" && item.value == "1")
        {
          $('#admCustRptSumm').attr('checked', true);
        }

        else if (item.field == "admCustRptDtl" && item.value == "1")
        {
          $('#admCustRptDtl').attr('checked', true);
        }

<input type="checkbox" id="admCustRptDly" name="admCustRptDly" class="admChkbx">
<input type="checkbox" id="admCustRptSumm" name="admCustRptSumm" class="admChkbx">
<input type="checkbox" id="admCustRptDtl" name="admCustRptDtl" class="admChkbx">
```

Answer (score 2):

your jquery is off, this doesn't quite give the response you'd expect, rather to find if a check box is checked:

```
var checked = $("#admCustRptDtl:checked").val();
```

Also, the checked attribute will never equal true, the html is actually checked="checked"

Answer (score 2):

```
 else if (item.field == "admCustRptDly" && item.value == "1")
```

I don't understand what are you trying to do here? I'm guessing you are trying to verify the value of "admCustRptDply" checkbox. Maybe post also the code before this.
You can get the value like this:

```
 var val = $("#admCustRptDly").val()
```

But in your HTML the checkboxes don't have a value attribute.

You can get the checked property of a checkbox like this:

```
var checked = $("#admCustRptDly").attr("checked")
```

And you can set it like this:

```
$("#admCustRptDly").attr("checked","checked")
```

Comment: I realize this answer is from 2009 but wanted to point out a few things that have been clarified in the meantime: You should set checked="checked" only when it's a string attribute in the HTML code. Once the page is rendered, checked becomes a _boolean property_, so technically here it's better to set true/false, not "checked". And, these days with jQuery 1.6+, it's better to use .prop("checked",true) rather than .attr(...)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please expand? Some example code would be very helpful, you might've just misspelt the checkbox name when trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I posted some code above. I'm sure its simple but I haven't a clue.